# How to render 2 Cameras onto one screen (in Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

I want to implement something like foveated rendering in Unity using different cameras with different image effects applied. How can i achieve that? Using render textures to merge the output of the cameras is no option for me :( If I try to set a smaller viewport for one camera I have problems to match that viewport to the bigger viewport of the other camera. (here is a sketch of the camera setup I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/okziQ.jpg)
Additional I would like to have a round shape for the smaller camera. What is the best technique to do it?

Edit: I have another picture to clarify my problem. I want the smaller view to match the bigger view perfectly
[image]

Comment: Use RenderTexture work with me. :D